# Improved bi-directional language support

Tags: macos, input-languages, iwork-pages

In the new features for Pages 2014 Yosemity, they say that they have : Improved bi-directional language support. What does it really mean?

Answer (score 0):

We're talking about bi-directional (right-to-left) languages like Arabic or Hebrew.

See [Wikipedia about this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bi-directional_text) for more info...